# struts2 <s:iterator> with <s:param> not working

Tags: struts2

I am displaying the list values with  tag.At the same time i want to provide a hyperlink for the displaying values to provide action for the displaying value.I am using `<s:param>` for that.but the values are not passing.I am writing like below

```
<s:iterator status="stat" value="transactionList">
        <s:url id="open" action="openTransaction">
              <s:param name="transactionCode" value="<s:property value='monthName'/>"/>
         </s:url>
 <tr class="gradeB">
  <td>
    <s:a href="%{open}"><s:property value='transactionCode'/></s:a>
  </td>
  <td><s:property value="monthName"/></td>
  <td><s:property value="transactionDesc"/></td>

  </tr>
  </s:iterator>
```

Now the `transactionCode` property is displaying with hyperlinks and by clicking on that the action is forwarding to `openTransaction` method.but the value i passed with `<s:param>` is not going,it is giving null. In iteration for that particular transaction code i want to pass that particular transaction code only. In struts 1.x I used display tag table decorator for this purpose, it takes the current row object.Here also i want to pass the current row values to the action. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `<s:property>` tag to put a param inside an url you have to do it like that:

```
<s:url ...>
    <s:param name="foo"><s:property value="bar"/></s:param>
</s:url>
```

The [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/param.html) of `<s:param>` explains the difference between using this way of putting a param and your way.

> Note: When you declare the param tag, the value can be defined in either a value attribute or as text between the start and end tag. Struts behaves a bit different according to these two situations. This is best illustrated using an example:

```
<param name="color">blue</param> <-- (A) --> 
<param name="color" value="blue"/> <-- (B) -->
```

> In the first situation (A) the value would be evaluated to the stack as a java.lang.String object. And in situation (B) the value would be evaluated to the stack as a java.lang.Object object. 
>   For more information see WW-808.

**Edit:** Also remember that if you are using 2.1.x or higher, the `id` attribute of `<s:url>` is deprecated and it has been replaced with `var`. You can read it [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/url.html).

Comment: its working..thanks a lot..i have the idea of both the syntaxes of param tag..but i thought those both have same functionality..the documentation is clear..

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:url var="search" value="/image/search.action">
<c:forEach items="${filtersMap}" var="map">
<c:param name="filtersMap.${map.key}" value="${map.value}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

${filtersMap} is a map param from action